# HangFire Server Enable - Disable manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

During development of [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/) application with C# ASP.NET, and I decided to implement functionally where Admin can manage state of Server, jobs.

- List item

> Server Enable Disable state.  Using Enable Button click event Admin
>   can start JOB server so all the Fire and Forget and Recurrent job can
>   performed. And Disable button stop all the activities of JOB.

- Retrieve the current state of Server

> I want to retrieve current state of JOB server, So I can show is
>   server is on or Off.

- Retrieve state and enable / disable state of Jobs (Only recurrent).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to manage Server/Job created by Hangfire, you can use MonitoringApi or JobStorage to get there statuses.

**Sample Codes :**

```
var _jobStorage = JobStorage.Current;

// How to get recurringjobs
using (var connection = _jobStorage.GetConnection())
{
    var storageConnection = connection as JobStorageConnection;

    if (storageConnection != null)
    {
        var recurringJob = storageConnection.GetRecurringJobs();

        foreach(var job in recurringJob)
        {
            // do you stuff
        }
    }
}

// How to get Servers

var monitoringApi = _jobStorage.GetMonitoringApi();
var serverList = monitoringApi.Servers();

foreach( var server in serverList)
{
    // do you stuff with the server
    // you can use var connection = _jobStorage.GetConnection()
    // to remove server
}
```

From here you can play around with Hangfire.

Comment: I haven't done that before and I don't know if hangfire allows stopping of job while executing. All I know is you can delete while job is in enqueue state and requeue job if you want.

Comment: I have recurring job that executes every minutes. For some reason if i want that job to stop until i ask again to start by pressing a button. Can this be done using hangfire delete and re queue feature ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to disable a recurring task? In my case, my Hangfire exists as a console application. Do I need to stop and restart the console application in order to change the schedule of a recurring task?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher To disable a recurring job, you remove it.  Jobs in progress will finish. 
 Example: In Core, inject a IRecurringJobManager recurringJobs service, then use the service to dequeue the job:  recurringJobs.RemoveIfExists(nameof(JobName))